# Primefaces and ajax onsuccess event

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I use ajax `remoteCommand` component with Primefaces and this component updates `inputHidden` field with boolean value.

I call JS function on the `onsuccess` event of `remoteCommand` but it seems that my function is called before DOM update because when I test `inputHidden` value, this is not the right value but if I set interval to test 3s after, I have the right value...

Code :

```
<p:remoteCommand process="..." onsuccess="hideOrShowNotification();" />
```

First JS test :

```
function hideOrShowNotification(){
   alert($('#tabView\\:register_form\\:hiddenNotification').val()); 
}
```

Second JS test :

```
function hideOrShowNotification(){
  setInterval(function(){alert($('#tabView\\:register_form\\:hiddenNotification').val());}, 3000);  
}
```

In first case I receive `false` value and in second case I receive `true` value. The expected value is `true`.

So my DOM is not fully loaded when my JS function is called.

How can I call JS function after full loading of DOM ? I believed `onsuccess` event would do that but no apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Ok...it's the `oncomplete` event. I tested it before but perhaps I have forgotten to clear browser cache to reload new JS file.

**EDIT :** [link to primefaces tag documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/ajax.html)