# what is onSuccess,aJax in commandButton?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my xhtml I have:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{accountInfoBean.onChangePassword}"
    ajax="true" onsuccess="changePasswordDlgVar.show()"
    update=":changePassForm:changePasswordPanel" />
```

My bean:

```
private String password;
private String confirmPassword;


public void onChangePassword() {
    this.password = null;
    this.confirmPassword = null;
}
```

I don't understand how password changes in database and what are `onsuccess`, `ajax` and `update` attributes?

Comment: That functionality you need to do it manually using DB query

Answer (score 0):

`onSuccess` is pointing javascript function that is to be executed after server responded is complete and there is no error.

**EDIT**

looked around about it and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402264/primefaces-onclick-and-onsuccess-differences) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199964/primefaces-and-ajax-onsuccess-event) question plus [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/ajax.html).
From documentation about onsuccess `Client side callback execute before dom is updated.` 
I'll try to put explaining example bit later.

Comment: can you example a simple javascript function

Comment: @user3478624 `"alert('operation was successful');"`