# JSF difference between action, actionlistener, onClick

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF in my project. I am using a context menu from PrimeFaces. I see in `p:menuItem` we have `action`, `actionListener`, `onclick` methods. So my question is: When do I have to use `action`, `actionListner`, `onclick` and what is the order of execution?

Comment: At least a partial answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener

Comment: Also see: Other part: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9115951/757071

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `onclick` will be executed first. It is used to call a javascript function.
- `actionListener` is used when you want to have some ajax call to a
  method. That method should have the return type `void`, the method
      either take an `ActionEvent` as argument or no argument; it can
      also be    used for a non-ajax call but then the page will be refreshed.
- `action` is used to navigate to a different page; the method should 
  have the return type `String`.

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked before.
Action is used when you want to call a method in your backing bean. e.g

```
action="#{myBean.myMethod}"
```

the code for bean would be like

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean", eager = true)
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean{

myMethod(){
// your method code here
}

}
```

How ever action listener does the same except that it is triggered with an event

```
myMethod(Event e){
// your method code here
}
```

Note that event can be of any type.

onclick works before sending the ajax request i dont have much knowlegde aboput it... i only used it for the UI purposes for example closing a dialog box on clicking a button

```
<p:commandButton id="cancel"  value="Cancel"
                                    icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w"
                                    style="float:right;" onclick="PF("dlg").hide()" type="button">
                                </p:commandButton>
```

**SEE ALSO**

[Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/2819935)