# HTML and JSF PrimeFaces - Why actionListener doesn't execute when onClick is present?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces, controller

I'm using HTML and JSF Primefaces, for this part of the System, PrimeFaces are not enabled (don't know why), the matter is:

I have a button

```
<h:commandButton id="btnPrint"
    onclick = "switchDisabled();"
    actionListener="#{componentTrackingController.printReport()}"
    value="Print Report"
/>
```

onClick its executing and working well (it just disables some other buttons)
but actionListener is not. The fact is that when I delete the "onClick" line, actionsListener works fine.

My JavaScript Code is simple (but I think the problem is not here)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function switchDisabled(){
        askDisabled(document.getElementById('mainForm:cboURdependences'));
        askDisabled(document.getElementById('mainForm:btnPrint'));
        askDisabled(document.getElementById('mainForm:btnCloseReport'));
    }

    function askDisabled(elem){
        if (elem.disabled != true){
            elem.disabled = true;
        }else{
            elem.disabled = false;
        }
    }  

</script>
```

Comment: You're disabling your button when you do onclick, it's called prior to the submission, so it then cant submit / click a disabled button. You can create a ajax hook into 'onsuccess'  for your ajaxListener that then calls switchDisabled()

Comment: it automatically loads the report at loadingPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, it's doing it instantly.
There are a few ways you could fix this, (the ajax hook) or setTimeout in javascript.

```
<h:commandButton id="btnPrint"
    onclick = "setTimeout(function(){ switchDisabled() }, 1000);"
    actionListener="#{componentTrackingController.printReport()}"
    value="Print Report"
/>
```

This binds a timout to call your switchDisabled tag in 1 second (1000ms) - thus your ajax etc should of already been run and it binds it, you'll find you can probably change it to 500 or something even less, but you dont want it to fire it before your submit is called.

Refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp 
for more information

Comment: thank you very much guys !!!
onclick = "setTimeout(function(){ switchDisabled() }, 1000);"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jsf/PrimeFaces but per this question: [Primefaces onclick and onsuccess differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402264/primefaces-onclick-and-onsuccess-differences)

Try using "oncomplete":

```
<h:commandButton id="btnPrint"
    oncomplete = "switchDisabled();"
    actionListener="#{componentTrackingController.printReport()}"
    value="Print Report"
/>
```

From PrimeFaces documentation (3.5):

> **oncomplete**: Javascript handler to execute when ajax request is completed.

Comment: You can't call oncomplete on a h:commandButton - it requires ajax embedded, need to use p:commandbutton for oncomplete.

Comment: Mmm I assume p is for,partial, and the h:button works similar to the onclick/postback couple on aspx, am i kind of right ?

Comment: It's primefaces component, which wraps the standard h:commandButton, and does ajax submit by default, unless you use ajax="false" then it does standard form submit. It has its own oncomplete tags.